# Why is R's data.table so much faster than pandas?

Tags: r, pandas, data.table

I have a 12 million rows dataset, with 3 columns as unique identifiers and another 2 columns with values. I'm trying to do a rather simple task:
 - group by the three identifiers. This yields about 2.6 million unique combinations
 - Task 1: calculate the median for column `Val1`
 - Task 2: calculate the mean for column `Val1` given some condition on `Val2`

Here are my results, using `pandas` and `data.table` (both latest versions at the moment, on the same machine):

```
+-----------------+-----------------+------------+
|                 |      pandas     | data.table |
+-----------------+-----------------+------------+
| TASK 1          | 150 seconds     | 4 seconds  |
| TASK 1 + TASK 2 |  doesn't finish | 5 seconds  |
+-----------------+-----------------+------------+
```

I think I may be doing something wrong with pandas - transforming `Grp1` and `Grp2` into categories didn't help a lot, nor did switching between `.agg` and `.apply`. Any ideas?

Below is the reproducible code.
Dataframe generation:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from collections import OrderedDict
import time

np.random.seed(123)
list1 = list(pd.util.testing.rands_array(10, 750))
list2 = list(pd.util.testing.rands_array(10, 700))
list3 = list(np.random.randint(100000,200000,5))

N = 12 * 10**6 # please make sure you have enough RAM
df = pd.DataFrame({'Grp1': np.random.choice(list1, N, replace = True),
                   'Grp2': np.random.choice(list2, N, replace = True),
                   'Grp3': np.random.choice(list3, N, replace = True),
                   'Val1': np.random.randint(0,100,N),
                   'Val2': np.random.randint(0,10,N)}) 


# this works and shows there are 2,625,000 unique combinations
df_test = df.groupby(['Grp1','Grp2','Grp3']).size()
print(df_test.shape[0]) # 2,625,000 rows

# export to feather so that same df goes into R
df.to_feather('file.feather')
```

Task 1 in Python:

```
# TASK 1: 150 seconds (sorted / not sorted doesn't seem to matter)
df.sort_values(['Grp1','Grp2','Grp3'], inplace = True)
t0 = time.time()
df_agg1 = df.groupby(['Grp1','Grp2','Grp3']).agg({'Val1':[np.median]})
t1 = time.time()
print("Duration for complex: %s seconds ---" % (t1 - t0))
```

Task 1 + Task 2 in Python:

```
# TASK 1 + TASK 2: this kept running for 10 minutes to no avail
# (sorted / not sorted doesn't seem to matter)
def f(x):
    d = OrderedDict()
    d['Median_all'] = np.median(x['Val1'])
    d['Median_lt_5'] = np.median(x['Val1'][x['Val2'] < 5])
    return pd.Series(d)

t0 = time.time()
df_agg2 = df.groupby(['Grp1','Grp2','Grp3']).apply(f)
t1 = time.time()
print("Duration for complex: %s seconds ---" % (t1 - t0)) # didn't complete
```

Equivalent R code:

```
library(data.table)
library(feather)

DT = setDT(feater("file.feather"))
system.time({
DT_agg <- DT[,.(Median_all = median(Val1),
                Median_lt_5 = median(Val1[Val2 < 5])  ), by = c('Grp1','Grp2','Grp3')]
}) # 5 seconds
```

Comment: Using function : `%timeit` to do the timing in python

Comment: `data.table` is sorted when you set a key on a column(s). The operations on sorted columns are usually faster.

Comment: And also include `DT = setDT(feater("file.feather"))` in the timing part in R

Comment: @Wen `DT = setDT(feater("file.feather"))` is not relevant, the dataframe comes from an SQL database and the SQL extraction time is about the same. I used `feather` just to make sure both R and Python are dealing with exactly the same data and the example is reproducible. I will update the post later using `%timeit` but I don't think that matters - the processing time is really long and in one instance it didn't even finish

Comment: @SergeyBushmanov after sorting the dataframe, the performance in python has not improved. I updated my code to reflect that.

Comment: I just ran your Python test 1, while running the debugger in PyCharms on one of my projects, and `6.84 s ± 135 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)` not sorted.

Comment: Since versions change constantly and posts age, please always **always state the numeric version number, especially in benchmark posts**. "Current" as of 3/2018 would have been [pandas 0.22](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/releases) and unclear which version of [data.table](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/news/news.html), either devel version of 1.11 or else 1.10.4-3

Comment: "Why is R's data.table so much faster than pandas?" Because Matthew Dowle is brilliant. One of the many optimizations in data.table is that when using a by statement, memory is only allocated for the largest group and reused. This saves a bunch of time for tasks that would otherwise involve allocating and deallocating memory for every group.

Answer (score 3):

I can't reproduce your R results, I fixed the typo where you misspelled feather, but I get the following:

```
Error in `[.data.table`(DT, , .(Median_all = median(Val1), Median_lt_5 = median(Val1[Val2 <  : 
column or expression 1 of 'by' or 'keyby' is type NULL. Do not quote column names. Usage: DT[,sum(colC),by=list(colA,month(colB))]
```

As to the python example, If you want to get the median for each group where Val2 is less than 5 then you should filter first, as in:

```
 df[df.Val2 < 5].groupby(['Grp1','Grp2','Grp3'])['Val2'].median()
```

This completes in under 8 seconds on my macbook pro.

Comment: I'm not sure why the R code is throwing that error, looking over it seems fine - I'll actually run it later today, maybe I made a mistake copy-pasting.  As for the Python code you suggested - that's great, but the purpose is to have it all in one step. There are several other aggregations needed on different filters `Val2<10`, `Val2<15` etc, and the code could get hard to read. Another plus for `data.table` in this case

Comment: So I think the real answer to your question in this case is that Python is slower because the df.groupby() call has to make the groups (all 2.5 million of them) before it can call apply --  It is just evaluating a Python expression after all.   Whereas (I'm guessing here) the data.table takes the two operations as parameters and is able to optimize the order so it is doing the filter first and then aggregating which makes sense and keeps the number of groups much smaller.  I'm curious to see if I can find a faster alternative in Pandas.